# How to send a specific content from a xlsx file in text format using curl?

Tags: curl, libcurl

This is my code:

```
% curl -F smiles='O=C(C(=O)O)C' -F cutoff=0.6 -F limit=10 http://rest.genome.jp/simcomp/
```

but it execute one SMILES per time. I have 150K SMILES in a .xlsx file spreadsheet.

How can I run all my SMILES code (this a type of SMILE code: `O=C(C(=O))C )` present in my .xlsx file at once? For that, I imagine that curl should read each line of my .xlsx file, convert in text format and include in specific field of the code, isn't?

For each response I get a table like shown below, and I want to save each one of them in `.txt` files.

```
C00186  0.851852
C00256  0.851852
C01432  0.851852
C00109  0.803279
C00957  0.803279
C00168  0.803279
C00972  0.803279
C17265  0.803279
C00163  0.730769
C00048  0.730769
C21297  0.718750
```

Follows an example of my .xlsx spreadsheet. Each line represent a SMILES code

```
CCCCCc1cc(cc(c1)O)O
CCC(C)C1C(=NC(Cc2ccc(cc2)OCC=C(C)C)C(=O)N(C)C(C)C(=O)OC(Cc2ccccc2)C(=O)N2CCCC2C(=NC(C)C(=O)N1C)O)O
CCC(C)(C(=O)OCC1=CCN2CCC(C12)O)OC(=O)C
C/C/1=C\C(C)CC2(C)CCC(C34CCC(CC(C5C(=O)CC(C)(C(C6CCC7(CCCC(C(C)C(=O)OC8CC(C9(C(C(C)CCO9)O)O)OC8\C=C1)O7)O6)O)O5)O3)(CO)O4)O2
CC1CC2C3C(C)(CCCC3(C)C31CCC1(CC(O)OC1)O3)C(=O)O2
Cc1cc2C(c3cc(cc(c3C(=O)c2c(c1C(=O)C)O)OC1C(C(C(C(CO)O1)O)O)O)O)C1c2cc(C)c(C(=O)C)c(c2C(=O)c2c1cc(cc2OC1C(C(C(C(CO)O1)O)O)O)O)O
C=CC(C)(CCC1C2(C)CCCC(C)(C)C2CCC1(C)O)O
C(C1C(C(C(OCC2C(C(C(OCC3C(C(C(O)O3)O)O)O2)O)O)O1)O)O)O
CN1C2CCC(C1CC2O)O
C1C(C(CO)OC1n1cnc2c(N)ncnc12)O
```

Answer (score 0):

$ while IFS='' read -r smiles || [[ -n "$smiles" ]]; do echo -e $smiles"\t"; curl -F smiles=$smiles -F limit=1 http://rest.genome.jp/simcomp/;echo -e "\r" ; done < test.txt > 123.txt